# Prime and Factorization, prime divisor property

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $p$ be prime. Then if $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Proof:
Suppose  $p$ does not divide $a$
Then $\gcd (a,p) = 1$ since $p$ is prime.

$$ 1 = ma + np $$
$$ b = mab +npb$$

Since $p|map$ and $p|npb$ then $p|b$

I have a problem understanding that $p|map$, can anyone show me how this works?

Comment: You mean that $p$ divides $mab$? This is because $p$ divides $ab$.

Comment: Yes you are correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the initial condition is $p|ab$, so from this follows that $ab = pk$, where $k$ is some positive integer. Assuming that $gcd(p,a) = 1$, then from the Bezout Lemma follows

$$1 = ma + np$$
$$b = mab + npb$$

This is something that you've already done, now make the substitution and get:

$$b = mpk + npb$$
$$b = p(mk + pb)$$

Because the term in the parenthesis is integer it follows that $p|b$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Ahhh! I Missed ab=pk. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome, actually that's what we're here.